# Uncaught ReferenceError: MyOwnInput is not defined in react.js(formsy react)

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs, formsy-react

I am trying to validate my Login form and using example on https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react

I am new to both react and formsy.

I am getting error as "Uncaught ReferenceError: MyOwnInput is not defined"

my code looks like this

```
        import Formsy from 'formsy-react';
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import {Link} from "react-router";
        import {withRouter} from 'react-router';


       export default withRouter(class Testing extends React.Component{



constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        canSubmit: false
    };
}

enableButton() {
    this.setState({
        canSubmit: true
    });
}
disableButton() {
    this.setState({
        canSubmit: false
    });
}
submit(model) {
    someDep.saveEmail(model.email);
}
render() {
    return (
        <Formsy.Form onValidSubmit={this.submit} onValid={this.enableButton} onInvalid={this.disableButton}>
            <MyOwnInput name="email" validations="isEmail" validationError="This is not a valid email" required/>
            <button type="submit" disabled={this.state.canSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </Formsy.Form>
    );
}
  });
```

Comment: Where is the import for MyOwnInput component?

Comment: what you mean by Import Myowncomponent.... from where i have to import that?

Comment: i just heard that thing first time.

Comment: I don't understand what is MyOwnInput. import Formsy from 'formsy-react'  is for <Formsy> but MyOwnInput is the part of Formsy or your own component?

Maybe will be something like import MyOwnInput from     '../../components/common/MyOwnInput';

Comment: can you tell me, what exactly i have to write in that component.. like i am not getting you at all

Comment: import MyOwnInput from     '../../components/common/MyOwnInput';

Comment: okay.. let me do and check that

Comment: But you should use your path to component instead ../../components/common

Comment: Thanks man It solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing import for MyOwnInput

It will be something like:

```
import MyOwnInput from '../../components/common/MyOwnInput';
```